# How to get records which contain alphaNumeric characters + white-spaces

Tags: mysql, regex

How to get records which contain alphaNumeric characters + white-spaces.
**OR**  At-list single numeric character in name.

i.e spiderman 1, abc12 part1

**What I have done.:**

```
 select * from table t where t.name REGEXP '^[A-Za-z0-9]+$'
```

but it will gives only records which dont have white space : i.e abc123

**so  I also tried**

```
  select * from table t where t.name REGEXP '^[A-Za-z0-9 ]+$'
```

Now, it gives me some records which does not contain any numeric characters. i.e abcdefg hij

Comment: What does "OR At-list single numeric character" mean? It sounds like you actually mean "AND at least one numeric character".

Comment: @ Mr.Barmar sir, :: OR At-list single numeric character it mean: t.name =1   is valid record  which i want      but   t.name = aaaBBB is not valid , which i dont want.    in More detail : i want records like : 1, 1SpiderMan, 1 spiderman-Part 2,     , while I dont want :  spider_man, spiderMAN spider M A N, this records ... in hope this is  understandable , sorry for my poor English..n You are right "At-list single numeric character in name." is enough for my que..  thank you so much  for your valuable time and code to solve this .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE name REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$' AND name REGEXP '[0-9]'
```

Simpler:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE name REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*[0-9][a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$'
```

Comment: I came up with a simpler regexp.

Answer (score 0):

What about this: `^[\w\s]*$`, which will match any numbers or word characters or whitespaces.

Comment: MySQL regular expressions don't support escape sequences `\w` and `\s`. You have to use character classes `[[:alnum:][:blank:]]`.

Answer (score 0):

A digit may appear in the start, middle, or end. So we have to take care of these combinations too for which regex groups are used, like this:

```
select * 
from table t 
where t.name REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z ]+[0-9 ]+[a-zA-Z ]*$|^[0-9]+[a-zA-Z ]+[0-9]*$'
```