# How to replace numeric character with "%" in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

How to replace numeric character with "%" in MySQL ?

i.e :  abcd 1234 zz  => abcd %%%% zz

**What I have :**

```
Declare cursorVideoTitles cursor  for select temp_playList.VideoTitle 
      from temp_playList  where temp_playList.VideoTitle regexp '^[A-Za-z0-9]+$';
```

cursorVideoTitles  contain all alphanumeric video titles. now after this I need to replace numeric character with "%"

**Reason for this :** 
I need to search it in other table which have same alphabets. 
so 1st I take all those values in cursor variable and iterate it with like query,so i will get  matching records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't have a regular expression replace function, you have to replace each digit separately.

```
SELECT
    REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
                REPLACE(
                    REPLACE(
                        REPLACE(
                            REPLACE(
                                REPLACE(
                                    REPLACE(
                                        REPLACE(VideoTitle, '0', '%'),
                                        '1', '%'),
                                    '2', '%'),
                                '3', '%'),
                            '4', '%'),
                        '5', '%'),
                    '6', '%'),
                '7', '%'),
            '8', '%'),
        '9', '%') AS TitleMasked
```

Comment: where there is a will, there is a way :)

Comment: In all that crazy mayhem there's a missing `'` on the inner-most `REPLACE`, but this is how it's done.

Comment: Please see this link : I hope u can give me some idea for this issue too.. :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22505494/how-to-get-records-which-contain-alphanumeric-characters-white-spaces/22506120?noredirect=1#22506120

Answer (score -1):

The easiest thing I can think is something like:

SELECT REPLACE(‘abcd1234zz’, ‘1234’, ‘%%%%’);

This query looks if there are 1234 in a value and replace them with four %

Comment: He needs to replace all digits, not specifically `1234`. That was juset an example.

Comment: Oh ok. Well it's the same. He just has to reiterate it for every digit :)

Comment: Like my answer, you mean?

Comment: yes sir, thank you for your priceless code.. :) @ Barmar