# Select records containing non alphanumeric characters in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to create a query within DB2 that will select all records which contain non alphanumeric characters within a given field.  I have tried the code in the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22505494/how-to-get-records-which-contain-alphanumeric-characters-white-spaces) but it does not seem to work.  The information i am needing to search is address information, therefore spaces will be acceptable i.e.

Data Example        - 
10 The High Street  - Good, therefore dont show in report
10 The High-Street  - Bad, therefore show in report

Any help will be most appreciated

Comment: give me the sample code

Comment: Please post your code (not just link to another post) and explain what "does not seem to work" means.

Comment: The post you link to uses regexes, a feature which DB2 does not have.  You will have to come up with a different solution.

Comment: I have tried to use the below.

Comment: I have tried to use:- `SELECT * FROM PAYMENT WHERE NOT xmlcast(xmlquery('fn:matches($s, "^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*[0-9][a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$")' passing LONG_NAME AS "s") AS int)=0`. I have used the xmlcast before and it worked fine with another regular expression to determine if the first 2 characters are a letter and the second 2 are a number using `"^[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}"` When i run the above query all records are returned including the records that contain no special characters or spaces, both of which should not be returned

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17462802/how-to-find-special-characters-in-db2/17469776#17469776

Comment: Why is your regexp looking for a digit in the middle? Why not just `"^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$"` ?

Answer (score 5):

One option is to translate all of the known printable characters to an empty space, and test whether the result is greater than a single space.

```
select KEY_VALUE
from TABLE
where TRANSLATE(CHAR_COLUMN,'','ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890') <> '';
```

Comment: If you do it this way, the third parameter of TRANSLATE() should only list the characters that you want to be accepted. The characters at the end, i.e., `!@#$%^&*()-=+/\{}[];:.,<>? `, should probably be removed from the list.